# Ajax - PHP - Error cambio de estado button

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Dispongo de una tabla donde muestro usuarios con una columna/id de "estado". Donde tendrá dos valores: color verde `(activo, estado=1)` o color rojo `(inactivo, estado=0)`. Tengo el siguiente código para cambiar el estado pero me muestra el color verde inicial pero no me hace el cambio al clickear sobre el button.

**¿Dónde tengo el error?**

**index.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt"> <!-- table-hover === se selecciona la fila indicada con el raton -->
                    <center>
                    <!-- Indicamos el nombre de las columnas de la tabla a visualizar. -->
                    <!-- TABLE = crear una tabla        TR = crear una fila        TD = crear una columna -->
                    <tr>
                        <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Login</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Email</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Apellidos</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Ciudad</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Teléfono</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Fecha registro</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Estado</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                        </center>
                        </thead>
                    </tr>

                    </center>
                    <?php
                        //Extraemos la informacion de ambas tablas relacionadas con el foreign key (ID_OBLIGATORIO).
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_obligatorios JOIN usuarios_datos ON usuarios_obligatorios.ID_OBLIGATORIO = usuarios_datos.ID_OBLIGATORIO ORDER BY usuarios_obligatorios.ID_OBLIGATORIO ASC";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        $numero = 0;
                        //Mientras existen datos, los agregamos en la tabla (mediante filas).
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"05%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["ID_OBLIGATORIO"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["login"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["email"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["nombre"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["apellidos"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["ciudad"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["telefono"]."</font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"10%\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'>".$row["fecha_registro"]."</font></font></td>";

                                echo "<td width=\"08%\">" ?>
                                    <!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. (estado verde/rojo). -->
                                    <center>
                                        <?php
                                            $estado = 1;
                                            $class = "activo";
                                        ?>
                                        <button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" data-estado="<?php echo $estado?>" style="height: 14px; width:14px;"></button>
                                    </center>
                                <?php 
                                echo "</td>";   

                                echo "<td width=\"08%\">" ?>    
                                    <!-- Columna MODIFICAR usuarios. Nos redirige a modificar.php (formulario ya con los datos cargados) gracias a: <a href="modificar.php?Id=<?=$row["ID_OBLIGATORIO"]?>"> 
                                         Al pasar el raton encima de cada modificar, abajo en el navegador podemos ver el valor de cada ID: osmar.fyb3/modificar.php?Id=7 -->
                                    <center><a href="modificar.php?Id=<?=$row["ID_OBLIGATORIO"]?>"><img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';"></center> <?php echo "</td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"08%\">" ?> 
                                    <!-- Columna ELIMINAR usuarios (checkbox). Sabemos el valor de cada fila mediante: value="<?php echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']; ?>" 
                                         Al dar en el boton ELIMINAR_SELECCIONADOS, los borraremos. Guardamos los marcados en un array llamado seleccionados[] cuyo
                                         valor lo extraemos mediante: value="<?php echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']; ?>" 
                                    -->
                                    <center><img src="imagenes/eliminar.png" height='23' width='24' alt="Eliminar">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados[]" id="seleccionados" value="<? echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']; ?>">
                                    </center> <?php echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>"; 
                            $numero++;
                        }
                        mysql_free_result($result);
                    ?>
                </table>

                <!-- Boton ELIMINAR SELECCIONADOS -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="right">
                    <font face="verdana">
                    <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_seleccionados" id="eliminar_seleccionados" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estos usuarios?');" value="Eliminar seleccionados"></b></font><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <?php
                    //Si no existen datos ($filas == 0), icono de la BBDD vacia.
                    }else{
                ?><br/><h1><b><font size="16"><center>BASE DE DATOS SIN DATOS</center></font></b></h1><br/><center><img src="imagenes/bbdd.png" height="180" width="160"/></center>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            //Aqui va el codigo del boton eliminar_seleccionados...
            //Si pulsamos el boton "Eliminar seleccinados"... 
            if(isset($_POST['eliminar_seleccionados'])) {
                if(empty($_POST['seleccionados'])) {
                    echo "<center><h2>No se ha seleccionado ningun usuario.</center></h2>";
                }else{
                    foreach($_POST['seleccionados'] as $valor){
                        $res1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios_obligatorios WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO=".$valor."");
                        $res2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios_datos WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO=".$valor."");
                        $res3 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios_aficiones WHERE ID_OBLIGATORIO=".$valor."");
                    }
                    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>




<script>
    //Funcion al clickear el button del ESTADO.
    $('.activar').click(function(){
        //Recogemos el valor de la variable "data-estado".
        var estado = $('.activar').attr('data-estado'); 
        //Llamamos al cambiar_estado.php y le pasamos el valor a la funcion.
        $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(response){
            //Dato = responde = 0, entonces desactivamos (color rojo). 
            if(response == 0){
                $('.activar').removeClass("activo");
                $('.activar').addClass("inactivo");
            }else{
                $('.activar').removeClass("inactivo");
                $('.activar').addClass("activo");
            }
        //Retornamos de nuevo el dato.
        $('.activar').attr('data-estado', response); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
$('.activar').on('click', cambiarEstado);

function cambiarEstado () {
  var estado = $(this).attr('data-estado');
  $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado});
}
```

**cambiar_estado.php**

```
<?php
  $estado = $_POST['estado'];
  if ($estado == '1'){
    $dato = 0;
  }
  else{
    $dato = 1;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bueno, lo primero que haría seria evitar poner esos nombres a tus clases `css` y tambien agregar `.` ya que esa es la forma correcta de definir una clase.

```
.inactivo{
   background-color: red;
}
.activo{
   background-color: green;
}
```

Segundo, tu codigo `php` no devuelve nada, deberias agregar :

```
<?php
  $estado = $_POST['estado'];
  if ($estado == 1){
    $dato = 0;
  }
  else{
    $dato = 1;
  }
  echo $dato;
?>
```

Tercero, luego de recibir el dato, deberías cambiar la clase la cual tiene tu boton.

```
<?php
  $estado = 1;
  $class = "activo";
?>
<button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" data-estado="<?php echo $estado?>">Cambiar estado</button>


<script>
$('.activar').click(function(){
    var estado = $('.activar').attr('data-estado'); 
    $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(response){
        if(response == 0){
            $('.activar').removeClass("activo");
            $('.activar').addClass("inactivo");
        }else{
            $('.activar').removeClass("inactivo");
            $('.activar').addClass("activo");
        }
    $('.activar').attr('data-estado', response); 
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDICION**

Ya que cambiaste tu pregunta, no ocupe todo tu codigo pero hice un ejemplo que cambia el estado del boton que corresponde.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <td>
                Id
            </td>
            <td>
                Boton
            </td>   
        </thead>
    </tr>
    <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='id' data-id='$i'>$i</td>";
            $estado = 1;
            $clase = "activo"; 
    ?>
            <td><button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" data-estado="<?php echo $estado ?>">Boton</button></td>
    <?php
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Y el script quedo :

```
<script>
$('.activar').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var estado = row.find(".activar").attr('data-estado'); 
    alert(row.find(".id").attr('data-id'));
    console.log("estado "+estado)  
    $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(response){
    estado = response;
    console.log(estado);
        if(response == 0){
            row.removeClass("activo");
            row.addClass("inactivo");
        }else{
            row.removeClass("inactivo");
            row.addClass("activo");
        }
        row.find(".activar").attr('data-estado', estado); 
    });  
});
</script>
```

Al hacer click en el boton de la fila de la tabla, obtengo esa fila. Luego obtengo la clase "activar" de esa fila en particular (que es tu boton) y ahi obtengo datos, los envio y los modifico.

Al obtener `var row = $(this).closest("tr");` obtienes el `<tr>` completo, por lo tanto puedes acceder a sus `<td>`. Lo ideal seria que cada campo de tus usuarios tuviera una clase por ejemplo en este caso `class="id"`, con esto puedes buscar dentro de tu `<tr>` el `<td>` que tenga esa clase u otra. Y finalmente accedes a su atributo.

Comment: Gracias a ambos por la respuesta. Lo que pasa "sioesi" que me cambia el estado durante centésimas de segundo no es permanente. Y me lo cambia  a todos los usuarios de la tabla, no al que clickeo.

Comment: Si la funcionalidad es esa, deberias dejar todo tu codigo y explicar bien que quieres, porque si pones 1 caso en particular, la ayuda que te daremos sera para ese caso. Si te cambia todos los usuarios es porque tu dejaste aqui "una clase" y no una "id" como deberia referencias a cada usuario

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código entero de la tabla donde tengo una columna que se llama ESTADO, donde para cada usuario se muestra un boton para poder desactivarlo o activarlo (al guardar el usuario en la tabla, el boton es verde(activado)). Quisiera que cada ID tenga su propio button, para poderle darle permisos de activo/inactivo.

Comment: @omaza1990 ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: ¿Cómo podría decir en la misma línea de código 
{
<button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" data-estado="<?php echo $estado?>" style="height: 14px; width:14px;"></button>
}

la linea/ID al cual pertenece?

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta...

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo identificar el usuario/linea de la tabla al cual clickeo el button para activar o desactivar? Saber si clickeo el ID/usuario 7 o el ID/usuario 64

Comment: @omaza1990 actualizado

Comment: ¿No se podría recoger el valor del ID/usuario marcado el estado con una consulta query del tipo: value="<? echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']; ?>"

Comment: Tienes que agregar al <td> el tag id= ese valor, y luego po jquery haces referencia a esa id y buscas el val. Aunque yo lo seguiria ocupando como atributo.

Comment: Ya lo tengo agregado: 
<button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" id_estado="<? echo $row['ID_OBLIGATORIO']; ?>" data-estado="<?php echo $estado?>" style="height: 14px; width:14px;"></button>

Comment: A pero lo agregaste en el boton???? Entonces `row.find(".activar").attr('id_estado');`

Comment: Tengo el siguiente codigo:

<script>
$('.activar').click(function(){
    var estado = $('.activar').attr('data-estado'); 
    $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(r){
        if(r == 0){
            $('.activar').removeClass("activo");
            $('.activar').addClass("inactivo");
        }else{
            $('.activar').removeClass("inactivo");
            $('.activar').addClass("activo");
        }
    $('.activar').attr('data-estado', r); 
    row.find(".activar").attr('id_estado');
    });
});
</script>

y el error que me da es: row is not defined

Comment: No lo haz definido en ninguna parte, por oto lado todas tus variables con (.activar) no van a servir ya que por cada fila de la tabla creas una. Tienes que agregar si o si var row = $(this).closest("tr"); y luego con esa variable buscas  var estado = row.find(".activar").attr('data-estado');. Cada vez agregas mas y mas codigo a la pregunta sin dejadla clars. Deberias ver que se te ha dejado una solucion y tu deberias adaptarla a tu codigo, ya que nunca lo entregas todo.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias causas por las que el código puede no estar funcionando:

1. En el css falta un punto (`.`) para indicar clase. Tanto en boton0 como en boton1.
2. En la llamada AJAX (el `$.post`), no estás haciendo nada para leer el resultado o cambiar el estado del botón cuando se reciba el resultado de cambiar_estado.php.

   Te faltaría añadirle un tercer parámetro que sería la función a ejecutar cuando se reciba un resultado. Y que cambiaría la clase del botón dependiendo del valor obtenido.
3. En cambiar_estado.php estás realizando operaciones pero no devuelves su resultado, por lo que el JavaScript no recibe nada de vuelta.

   Te faltaría algo como `echo $dato;`.

---

A partir de la información y del nuevo código que has añadido a la pregunta:

```
//Funcion al clickear el button del ESTADO.
$('.activar').click(function(){
    //Recogemos el valor de la variable "data-estado".
    var estado = $('.activar').attr('data-estado'); 
    //Llamamos al cambiar_estado.php y le pasamos el valor a la funcion.
    $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(response){
        //Dato = responde = 0, entonces desactivamos (color rojo). 
        if(response == 0){
            $('.activar').removeClass("activo");
            $('.activar').addClass("inactivo");
        }else{
            $('.activar').removeClass("inactivo");
            $('.activar').addClass("activo");
        }
    //Retornamos de nuevo el dato.
    $('.activar').attr('data-estado', response); 
    });
});
```

El problema que tienes ahora es que en la función que controla el resultado del `$.post` estás usando las clase ".activar" que aparece en numerosos elementos y no sólo en el que se ha pulsado.

Prueba a cambiarlo para que en lugar de que todos los elementos con clase "activar" sean los objetivos, sea exclusivamente el que se pulsó:

```
//Funcion al clickear el button del ESTADO.
$('.activar').click(function(){

    // guardamos el elemento que se ha pulsado
    var $this = $(this);

    //Recogemos el valor de la variable "data-estado".
    var estado = $this.attr('data-estado'); 
    //Llamamos al cambiar_estado.php y le pasamos el valor a la funcion.
    $.post('cambiar_estado.php', {estado:estado}, function(response){
        //Dato = responde = 0, entonces desactivamos (color rojo). 
        if(response == 0){
            $this.removeClass("activo");
            $this.addClass("inactivo");
        }else{
            $this.removeClass("inactivo");
            $this.addClass("activo");
        }

        //Retornamos de nuevo el dato.
        $this.attr('data-estado', response); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar...

echo "<td width=\"08%\">" ?>
            <!-- Columna ESTADO del usuario. (estado verde/rojo). -->
            <center>
             <?php
           $estado = 1;
           $class = "activo";
          ?>
          <button class="activar <?php echo $class;?>" datadata-estado="<?php echo $estado?>" style="height: 14px; width:14px;"></button>
            </center>
        <?php 
           echo "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button type="button" name="btnestado3" id="btnestado3" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="btnestado(this.name)" data-modiestado="3">Inactivo</button>
```

JS

```
function btnestado(namess) {
//    alert(namess);
    var uno = document.getElementById(namess);
    var idestado = uno.dataset.modiestado;
    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("id", idestado);

    if (uno.innerText === 'Inactivo') {
        uno.innerText = 'Activo';
        uno.classList.remove("btn-danger");
        uno.classList.add('btn-success');
        formData.append("esta", 1);
        load(formData, direccion + "administrar/cambiarEstado/", function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("comentario").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        });
    } else {
        uno.innerText = 'Inactivo';
        uno.classList.add('btn-danger');
        uno.classList.remove('btn-success');
        formData.append("esta", 0);
        load(formData, direccion + "administrar/cambiarEstado/", function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("comentario").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$estado = $_POST["esta"];
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Tu respuesta quedaria mucho mejor si adjuntas una breve explicacion de lo que hace tu codigo :)